# Invalid JSON with Parse.com Request in Java

Tags: java, json, rest, parse-platform, request

I'm trying to copy Parse's Curl REST API code into Java as shown in their documentation [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest/guide#queries-query-constraints):

```
curl -X GET \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APPLICATION-ID" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: REST-API-KEY" \
-G \
--data-urlencode 'where={"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}' \
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore
```

Essentially, I'm trying to find a user's item in table Items based upon the selected user's objectid.

Currently, I'm just testing by running my program as a Java application but I'm getting a {"code":107,"error":"invalid JSON"} error from the response. I just can't seem to get the data-urlencode of the curl correct (or it could be I'm completely doing it wrong). If it matters, I'm using OkHttp.

Here is my code below:

```
public List<Item> getItemList(String user) {
    final MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    String userID = getUserID(user);
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    System.out.println(userID);
    if(userID != null) {

        String json = "'where={\"Owner:\"" + userID + "\"}'";
        RequestBody reqBody = RequestBody.create(JSON, json );

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Items")
        .header("Content-type", "application/json")
        .post(reqBody)
        .addHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", REST_API_KEY)
        .addHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", APPLICATION_ID)
        .build();

        Response resp;
        try {
            resp = client.newCall(request).execute();
            String html = resp.body().string();
            System.out.println("Html is: " + html);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    } else {
        return null; //TODO: Throw no user found exception
    }
      return null;
}
```

It looks ugly, but right now I'm just trying to get it to work. The getUserId() method works correctly and returns the correct user ID string. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: which requestBuilder implementation are you using?  from Curl -X POST -d --> post.entity . however, IMO Curl -X GET -G "encode"  --> RequestBuilder.addParameters ....   http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/RequestBuilder.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you've understood what the "--data-urlencode" option does to the curl request. The request the curl line sends looks something like the encoded version:

```
encoded > https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore?where=%7B"playerName"%3A"Sean%20Plott"%2C"c
decoded > https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore?where={"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}
```

This is a GET-request, as specified in the documentation, and it looks like you're trying to send a POST-request. Have you tried to send a GET-request with the data url-encoded?

Comment: You're right. I was completely lost at that point. Eventually, I was able to send a correct GET request to Parse. It was also the fact my encoding was incorrect. Oddly, OKHttp's HttpUrl.Builder() encoding doesn't seem by default to encode curly braces { } even though they're RFC 1738 unsafe characters.

Thanks for saving me hours of work, Petter.